# Connection Atmega8 with MPU6050

Tags: atmega, mpu6050

I have question, because I have problem with connection Atmega8 with mpu6050 by means of I2C.

This is my connection:

[image: enter image description]

Is this a good connetion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connections look good.
MPU6050 module has on board 3.3v regulator. 
The module has also on board pull up resistors for I2C communication. So simply we can connect it directly without any extra components.

You can find this document useful:  http://www.electronicwings.com/avr-atmega/mpu6050-gyroscope-accelerometer-temperature-interface-with-atmega16

Answer (score 1):

answer will depend of the board used. MPU6050 is basically a 3.3V chip (not 5V). But if the daughter board is well designed (and boards designed to work for Arduino are) the connection seems to be OK.

Some more information may be accessible here : [enter link description here](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050)